# Dynamically changing HttpClient.Timeout in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I need to change a `HttpClient.Timeout` property after it made a request(s). When I try, I get an exception:

> This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Set it before the request??

Comment: @L.B., The message is clear. But I still wonder is there any trick to avoid this. geedubb, I need to change after.

Comment: @ValeO the value of `Timeout` is used to set `CancelAfter` on the `CancellationTokenSource` before the async task is started (internally). So, even if you could change it afterwards, through some "trick", it would have no effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't much you can do to change this. This is just default behavior in the HttpClient implementation.

> The Timeout property must be set before the GetRequestStream or GetResponse method is called.
>   [From HttpClient.Timeout Remark Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In order to change the timeout, it would be best to create a new instance of an HttpClient.

```
client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = 20; //set new timeout
```

Comment: Beware: creating/disposing the `HttpClient` might cause socket exhaustion problems: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I'd recommend against this. See argument in link provided by @Monsignor. You can use this approach instead:
https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/

Answer (score 17):

Internally the `Timeout` property is used to set up a `CancellationTokenSource` which will abort the async operation when that timeout is reached. Since some overloads of the `HttpClient` methods accept `CancellationTokens`, we can create helper methods to have a custom timeouts  for specific operations:

```
public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string requestUri, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri, cts.Token)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that any Timeout set on the HttpClient will still be enforced. This can only reduce the time it takes for a request to timeout; it can't increase it.

Answer (score 6):

Lack of support for custom request-level timeouts has always been a shortcoming of `HttpClient` in my mind. If you don't mind a small library dependency, [Flurl.Http](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl) [disclaimer: I'm the author] supports this directly:

```
"http://api.com/endpoint".WithTimeout(30).GetJsonAsync<T>();
```

This is a true request-level setting; all calls to the same host use a shared `HttpClient` instance under the hood, and concurrent calls with different timeouts will not conflict. There's a configurable global default (100 seconds initially, same as `HttpClient`).